# How to increase the size of the OS X user interface without lowering the resolution?

Tags: font, ui, resolution, accessibility

I can adjust a few things, such as the Dock, but I don't see a way to say, "I want 1080p resolution, but I'm sitting 5 feet away and want bigger menus, fonts, etc across the entire system."

This is for a computer to be used as an entertainment center, mac mini 2007 running OS X 10.6.8.

I can upgrade to Lion if that provides a useful solution.

How do I increase the sizes of everything system wide so it's readable from a distance, while keeping the high resolution I desire for movies and games?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a feature that's currently experimental called **HiDPI** that may do what you want. Like the retina displays on the iPhone and iPad, HiDPI mode creates a "logical" resolution that's half the current resolution on your display but uses all the physical pixels to keep the image sharp. This results in all the user interface elements appearing much larger, but with no lack in clarity. For example, if you're outputting to a 1080p TV with a resolution of 1920x1080, the HiDPI resolution would be 960x540, and all the elements on the screen would be the same size as if you were outputting that physical resolution.

**To enable HiDPI mode in Mac OS X Lion:**

1. Download the "Graphics Tools for Xcode" download from Apple. This download requires you to enter an Apple ID, which you most likely have and can get for free.
2. Mount the DMG
3. Open the "Quartz Debug" app
4. In the menu bar, select "Window", then "UI Resolution"

   [image]
5. Check "Enable HiDPI display modes"
6. You'll be prompted to log out and log back in. If multiple accounts are logged in, they must all log out for the change to work.
7. Once you log back in, go to System Preferences, then Displays. You will see the new HiDPI modes there.

   [image]
8. For your 1080p TV, select "960x540 (HiDPI)"

*P.S. If you're curious what HiDPI mode looks like, the screenshots I've taken are both in HiDPI. Click on them to see them full sized.*

Comment: I can't check it now (no pre-lion machines), but I think the Quartz Debug app let you do something like this pre-lion, but it was REALLY bad.

Comment: @jmlumpkin Yeah, I remember playing around with it years ago and you're right, nothing looked good at all. With this, it looks like it could almost ship

Comment: Thats what I heard. I think previously safari was the only thing close.

Comment: Hello, I am also looking for a solution to [increase the font size](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46126/increase-font-size-in-os). I have tried what you proposed, but the biggest resolution is `960x600 (HiDPI)` which makes the font too big for me. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @SoftTimur I'm sorry, but HiDPI is designed to be a 2X multiple of existing resolutions. 2X was chosen because it scales well. Apple had been playing with other multiples in past years, but never got it to look or work properly

Comment: OK... I have installed this `Graphics Tools for Xcode` (including `Quartz Debug`), do you know how to uninstall it, so that my system comes to what it was earlier?

Comment: @SoftTimur The HiDPI resolutions are provided in addition to, instead of, the standard resolutions in Displays. However, disabling them is as easy as going into Quartz Debug and unchecking the HiDPI option. Once that's done, you can trash the Graphics Tools for Xcode DMG that you downloaded.

Comment: So removing DMG is equivalent to removing the installation (actually nothing has been really installed in the OS)?

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of apps don't fit onscreen or resize nicely to 960x540. The displays prefpane applet warns you about this if you switch to any resolution less (in either direction) than ye olde 1024x768, and it's right... and unless you've got a cinema display, all the HiDPI resolutions are indeed less than 1024x768.

Comment: Thanks, hidpl helped, tv pioneer 52" as media center. But still apple should seriously consider upscale option. I Refused to work on mac air 13", and sold it after a week of unpleasant experience due to same problem, hidpl not really usefull on it.

Comment: Does this work for MacOS Mojave?

Comment: @AaronFranke You could probably use a tool like SwitchResX to do it, but I don't know if you can do it just with System Preferences

Answer (score 6):

Better yet, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool YES
```

(enter the admin password).

Log out and back in, and Bob's yer uncle.

Answer (score 4):

As of Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8), the HiDPI feature is no longer experimental. It's available in standard installs of the OS, without messing around with developer tools. But it still doesn't work as well as I'd like for this purpose, because if you're using a TV at the normal full HD resolution (1080P, or 1920x1080), the HiDPI resolution of 960x540 is too small for a lot of apps. iTunes, the Mac App Store, and even the Mountain Lion installer and welcome screens either force scrollbars on all screens (annoying) or truncate content without letting you scroll to see it (even worse).

HiDPI is probably the only answer to this problem we're going to get from Apple, but it's really not the right one. It would be nice if people would design their apps to run well at 960x540, but I'm not betting on it.

Comment: So, how do I enable this without installing XCode? I've tried to do what Lauri Ranta did, but was unsuccessful. Have you done the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable the HiDPI modes without Quartz Debug by changing `DisplayResolutionDisabled` to `DisplayResolutionEnabled` in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist` and logging out and back in.

The maximum effective resolutions are half of the native resolutions.

[image]

Comment: I've just done what you said in 10.8.2 but no HiDPI options appeared. (I do not have XCode installed.) Instead, after logging out and back in the menubar's option to be transparent was removed and could not be re-enabled. So I decided to reboot. After a reboot I had a very poor graphics performance. No idea how such a little change could have such a radical effect. Changing the value back did not help. Instead, I had to restore the file with Time Machine. All of this does not really make sense to me. But I just thought you should know.