# How can I force specific HiDPI modes?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, displayport, resolution

I have a 13" MBP (Early 2011) plugged it to a Dell U2711 monitor via DisplayPort.

I have successfully enabled HiDPI mode, using [Quartz Debug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45719/26063) the problem is that the screen won't run at the HiDPI equivalent of the screen's native resolution. i.e 1440x720 HiDPI (2560x1440). The screen's maximum resolution of 2560x1440 **is** recognised & working.

[image: Native resolution detected & working]

The best it will do is 960x720HiDPI (1920x1440), which seems strange as most of the documentation suggests HiDPI will only work at pixel doubling resolutions.

[image: Missing specific HiDPI mode]

Is it possible to force the MBP to run the display at 1440x720 HiDPI on a screen that supports 2560x1440 native pixel resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of messing about I managed to get this working in two ways.

1. The first is by using the [Retina Display Manager](http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/vi9yf/set_your_retina_macbook_pros_resolution_to/) I found on reddit.
   This gives a menu with all the available display modes, **but** try the second method first.
   [Screenshot 1 (Warning, large file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYdfu.png)
2. The second I found after using Retina Display Manager, to my surprise the **Displays** pane in **System Preferences** was reporting it was running in 720p mode.
   This mode is **actually** 1280x720 HiDPI (2560x1440).
   [Screenshot 2 (Warning, large file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0BoA.png)

Yay!

I was going to embed screenshots of these new menus, but they are now insanely huge due to HiDPI mode, so I just linked to them instead.

Comment: is this still working for you on yosemeti/el-capitan? I have the same monitor you do, and I can't get hidpi to work. Choosing 720p like you did gets me actual 720p.

Comment: On El Capitan (or at all), I cannot reach HiDPI 1280x720... - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276205/1280x720-hidpi-resolution-for-2560x1440-monitor