# What screen capture tools can copy the image path to the clipboard after a snap?

Tags: software-recommendation, screen-capture, utilities

Can anyone recommend a screen capture tool that can:

1. save a capture as a file, and...
2. copy the path to that file to the clipboard?

The first part is easy, but I can't find a utility that does the second part.

I dont need another app if there's a way to configure this using the built-in screen capture tool.

Comment: There might be other ways to get to your ultimate goal. What do you want to do with the path in the clipboard afterwards?

Comment: I'm pasting the file paths into a Markdown file as I take notes during screencasts. The workflow I'm after is to take the capture and quickly paste the path into markdown so the captured image appears in my output file. Would welcome any suggestions - also trying out Lri's solution now.

Comment: So you probably need a way to specify the path before taking the screenshot as well (otherwise your file links will break afterwards). Hmm, Automator maybe?

Comment: Yep - specifying the path was the key as shown in Lri's script. The FastScripts app that Lri recommended then worked perfectly for executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

f=~/"Desktop/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').png"
screencapture -i "$f"
echo -n "$f" | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 pbcopy
```

See `man strftime` for a reference of the date format.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, thank you - and you taught me a new skill in the process. Thanks again

Comment: Any chance you also know how to tell the bash script to capture at higher resolution? I'm happy to post this as a new question if you prefer.

Comment: What do you mean by higher resolution? Like when [using a HiDPI mode](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45716)? It should probably be another question though.